# iAd Workbench adds not running

Tags: ios, iad

I've setup two iAd campaigns through iAd Workbench. One is fully automatic and another manual. The system says the campaigns are running and predicts many thousands of adds will be viewed, yet the status reports over the last couple of days indicates no adds have been run, no views and no clicks. Has anyone had similar issues and found a solution?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I'm more than 1 day into my campaigns (set up exactly like you: 1 auto, 1 manual), with no spend and no downloads). Weird.

Comment: @SideOfBacon, I had to raise the bid by about 10-15X then the adds started running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started an iAd Wordkbench campaign on 6/12 using Manual and restricted my target audience such as user preferences and geography. I didn't see results until I edited my campaign to include all 50 states and include more categories. I set a CPA of $0.83. My goal was to simply expose my new app to more potential users.

I started to see impressions and taps the next day, but have 0 downloads. So the ROI isn't good. You can read more about it in my [post](http://rayvinly.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-iad-workbench-to-promote-your-ios-apps/). I will write more details with numbers, charts, and sales numbers in a follow up post.

Comment: Nice post. I set a similar CPA and sold one app after spending tens of dollars. I let it go 3 days and paused the campaign.

Comment: Seeing the same problem, see here: http://www.digitalruby.com/the-new-iad-workbench-for-the-little-guys/